# Replace default "Choose an Option" text in Magento layered navigation dropdown

Tags: magento, layered-navigation

I am using dropdowns to display my layered navigation attribute values. I have 3 filters - price, size and color. 
This is what I am trying to do:
1. Get dropdowns for the layered navigation filters.
2. Get the attribute label/name to show up as the first option. Currently, my code puts a default "Choose an Option" value for each dropdown, which I would like to replace with something like "Choose Price", "Choose Size" and "Choose Color".
Here is my current code for template/catalog/layer/filter.phtml. The dropdown works, but I am stuck at getting the attribute label instead of "Choose an Option"

```
<select onchange="setLocation(this.value)">
<option value='' disabled selected style='display:none;'>Choose an Option</option>
</option> 
<?php foreach ($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
<option
    <?php if ($_item->getCount() > 0): ?>
    value="<?php echo $this->urlEscape($_item->getUrl()) ?>"><?php echo $_item->getLabel() ?>
    <?php else: echo '>' . $_item->getLabel() ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    (<?php echo $_item->getCount() ?>)
</option>
```

Comment: Can you please give more details on how you managed to use dropdowns instead of native `<a>` filters?

Comment: Ok, the "Choose an Option" was not present in the default filter.phtml. Posting the old and new code in my question.

Comment: Vote to close: installation specific, not generic for Magento questions. Cannot you just grep your files for the text to find out where it originates from?

Comment: Well, I am trying to solve what should be a simple issue - get the attribute values in a dropdown, and then show the label as the default option. I got the first part from one of the boards, and am trying to figure out how to do the second. I am sure a lot of people would be interested in a solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code. It is tested in all the browsers.

```
<select onchange="setLocation(this.value)">
<?php $count = 0; ?>
 <?php foreach ($this->getItems() as $_item): ?> 
 <?php $count++; ?>
 <?php if($count == 1): ?>
<option value='' disabled selected style='display:none;'>Choose <?php echo $attribute_code = $_item->getFilter()->getName();?> </option> 
<?php endif; ?>
<option <?php if ($_item->getCount() > 0): ?> value="<?php echo $this->urlEscape($_item->getUrl()) ?>">
<?php echo $_item->getLabel() ?> <?php else: echo '>' . $_item->getLabel() ?> <?php endif; ?> (<?php echo $_item->getCount() ?>) </option>
<?php endforeach; ?> 
</select>
```

Comment: Ok, it looks like there is a problem in Safari and IE. I get the drop down with the filter name repeated again and again. Like so: (For the price filter) - Choose Price, $0.00 - $49.99, Choose Price, $50.00 - $99.99, Choose Price etc. Clicking on any of the repeated 'Choose Price'values gives a 404 error. The error is only seen on Safari and IE. In IE, I can't actually select the 'Choose Price' value, but in Safari, I can, and this leads me to a 404 page. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Thanks! Works well on all browsers.